# Specify Very large numbers use in C

Tags: c, bitvector

I'm thinking of using big large integers one way i can think is using  [Gmplib](https://gmplib.org/), i worked with small examples, but can it work with numbers like 2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ 1024)) ??

My question is how to represent that big number because (not sure) calculators too might get an overflow.

Comment: "I want to do X, one way to do it is by using FooLib. ... Is there any library for that?" ... Errr... what? You just answered your own question!

Comment: You will need 2^(2^1024) bits to store this number. Have you got that many bits?

Comment: @KerrekSB: http://mrob.com/pub/perl/hypercalc.html

Comment: The number `2^(2^1024)` cannot be stored without losing accuracy.

Comment: How many atoms does the universe have? General rule is to first think before posting a question.

Comment: @KerrekSB I can do that storing in an array of length 2 ^ N and each index of length 2 ^ N array . But the prob was compatibility because if i use int i'm restricted to 32 bit i have to use array trick. I can write a library that can take care but my use case little diff. I'm new to C that's why i have asked. Thanks rici

Comment: What's the difference between storing 1023 and storing 0b1111111111? Binary computers can't store decimal values like 1023

Comment: I'm talking about only specifying it. rather than saying take from 0 to 1023 which will become very huge for N = 20. I can represent it as bitvector[10].

Comment: What bits represent is defined by the programmer. A variable that can represent either `0` or `2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 1024))` takes 1 bit. A variable that can represent any number in the range `-128 * 2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 1024))` to `128 * 2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 1024))` takes 8 bits. Languages and CPUs have built-in support for a very small variety of representations; but this is only an inconvenience and not a restriction. The inconvenience includes (e.g.) writing `char myNumber = 1;  // Represents 1 * 2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 1024))` when the compiler can't handle your representation of numbers itself.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking of using big large integers one way i can think is using Gmplib, i worked with small examples, but can it work with numbers like 2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ 1024)) ??

No. GMP has two operating modes: large integers and large floating-point numbers. The first one can only operate on numbers whose integer value can be fully represented in memory; the second is limited to exponents that can be represented within about 64 bits. The number you're describing does not fit within either of those limits. (The exponent alone is too large to fit into memory!)

> My approach : I'll try to reduce noise by storing them as binary numbers / bitvectors because it'll give me get away with > one 2^ step.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to say here or in the following paragraph, but what you're describing sounds like a typical multiprecision integer implementation. It's no different from what GMP does to store large integers, and it won't work for this application.

Numbers of the scale you're describing are not easy to work with. Whether you find a library to work with them or write one yourself, it'll likely need to be designed specifically for the purpose of operating on numbers with this particular structure. They're simply too large to do anything else with.

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure whether something is already there or not. By My Approach i meant was rather than specifying choose number between 0 to 15  i can represent same specification as choose from 0000 to 1111 or directly *bitvector[4].

Comment: @user2754673 The approach you're describing is already how computers store integers. It's not something new or different.

Comment: No. I even not suggesting anything. I'm just stating a way that to specify 1023 u can get away with just specifying bitvector[10]. Nothing more. I understand that's how computer stores them. I was just asking is there any way to somehow represent that somehow takes care of the overflow coz if i have to do it i have to store each one 32 bitvector in an array that's not cool.